# swift:Different alignment of views in same view controller

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout

How can i make a view like this. I am done with first portrait mode and confuse to to achieve the landscape mode.? can anybody suggest me how to make the view in landscape mode. I have done portrait mode in AnyHeight AnyWidth format. 
[image]

Comment: Check this http://imnotyourson.com/ios-adaptive-layout-with-rotation-tips/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Although the question might be a little broad, I'll try to mention a generic answer.*

Assuming that your are already familiar with *Auto Layout* and *Size Classes*, in Xcode 8, Interface Builder you can change the current view of what are you working on:

[image]

By tapping the "View as:" button, you will be able to see the desired device orientation to setup the desired layout via device configuration bar:

[image]

**For example**, Consider the following View:

[image]

As yo can see, both of the views have the desired constraints to be displayed in portrait mode, for now, you should add add new constraints for the landscape mode. *Make sure* to *deinstall* the constraints for portrait mode:

[image]

As you can see, some of the constraints appears faded, which means that they are uninstalled on this size class. You can determine installing the constraint by selecting it and from the attribute inspector, check the desired size class(es):

[image]

For more details about how you can achieve this, I would suggest to watch [Making Apps Adaptive, Part 1 Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Right now i dont have a mac. But once i made my view in Portrait mode and and see it in landscape mode. and deinstalling the constraints for portrait mode while in landscape mode... doesn't it effect for pootriat mode.??

Comment: That's right, the uninstalled constraints from the landscape mode will not be activated and affects in the portrait mode

Comment: yes i will try it tomorrow and i will ask if there is a problem :) : ) thank you